Will a URL with a static query parameter work in an engagement split if you don't need the query string tracked?
Say I have the following static URL:
https://thisisatest.com?query-parameter
In my journey, I want to exit any user who clicks that URL.
When configuring this as an engagement split, SFMC lists the URL as:
https://thisisatest.com
and states that 'URLs can't contain query parameters'
If I select https://thisisatest.com when configuring the engagement split, will some who clicks https://thisisatest.com?query-parameter be exited out of my journey?
I don't care if the query string is removed from any tracking, I just want a click to that static link to be evaluated in the engagement split.
